# Alter table throw error #1005

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have two different table as follows

```
apis
users
```

Here `users` table has `api_id` as a forien key.

Now am executing the following query but it is thorwing error
(stating that the `api_id` column references the `id` column on the `apis` table.)

```
alter table `users` add constraint users_api_id_foreign foreign key (`api_id`) references `apis` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade
```

**Error**: `#1005 - Can't create table 'xxxxx.#sql-54ef_229ff39' (errno: 150) (<a href="server_engines.php?engine=InnoDB&amp;page=Status&amp;token=50174b3c687a6edcb259e10dd65ca6d7">Details...</a>)`

**MySQL version (development server)**

```
Server version: 5.5.42-37.1-log
```

**The same query working in my localhost**

```
Server version: 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
```

How can I fix this error? Thanks in advance.

**Apis Table**

[image]

**Users Table**

[image]

Comment: Does the api_id exist in users table? if yes, do they have the same data type?

Comment: truncate both of the tables and then add the foreign key..

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this problem is caused by if you already have data in your table.
In your case if you have any data in `users` table then first truncate users table and try again.

Comment: yes, basically Laravel first creating schema then executing seeder file for inserting data.